# wpf canvas background image dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, canvas

In my application I want the user to load an image as the canvas background. How can I assign the image to canvas background?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use ImageBrush to set Canvas.Background property

```
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"sampleImages\berries.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
mycanvas.Background = ib;
```